# Mouse pointer failing Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: mouse, mouse-pointer

Mouse, is working but not properly, since some time ago. Issue is that it points, for example on a link, but not exactly as it should be.

my mouse pointer is a bit above the link,  still it's clicking the link,  even when it is not on the click. 
I'm trying my best here to explain the bug,  hope you understand me guys...  I'm not able to post images yet,  so I praise that I'm explaining myself properly...

I tried to restart the mouse controllers an the terminal,  activate/deactivate,  didn't work either,  even tried to solve it changing the mouse options on unity tweak tool,  and tweak tool.  Nothing worked.

Crazy thing is that this clicking issue is also present navigating on Ubuntu file Explorer and menus,  which makes me even more confused yet...

It's not a life of death bug,  I'm starting  to get used to it,  but still would be nice to work with  a normal pointer.

Any ideas??? 
As usual any help is much appreciated

[Image Bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e26t1.jpg)

Comment: Have you tested another mouse?

Comment: Yep, I did. Problem is still there, even when working with touchpad, so it seems to be more of an ubuntu bug than physical device...